# join all values of a field on a dataset in report

Tags: jasper-reports, field

I have a dataset in *JasperReports* report  which has two fields ID and Name.

And I want to write Filter Expression for the report itself ie the report should be displayed only if all the Name values on the dataset has string "Success".

Lets say,
I have two tuples in the dataset like

```
Case 1:
(1,'Failure')
(2,'Success')

Case 2:
(1,'Success')
(2,'Success')

Actual Result:
   Case 1 & Case 2: report is displayed

Expected Result:
   Case 1: report should be displayed
   Case 2: report should not be displayed.
My Expression:
   "Success".equals($F{Name}) ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE
```

My current expression returns true even if anyone of the Name field has "Success" string.

Hence I need a valid expression which provide me the above expected results.

Please help me.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: `"Success".equals($F{Name}) ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE` - Your expression looks right

Comment: My expression returns true even if anyone of the Name field has "Success". But I want to return true only if values of all Name fields in the dataset have "Success".

Or can we get all values of Name field in the dataset? Then  I can use it in the expression. like converting the Name field values into ArrayList or something? I found slightly similar kind of requirement in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997770/reporting-services-join-all-field-on-a-dataset but it is for Sql server reporting services.