# SSRS: Using tablix with multiple Dataset

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have two datasets:

My First dataset (Students) looks like this:

```
Student_Name| ID
Jack Luis   | 1
Adam Bob    | 2
```

And my second dataset (Exam) looks like this:

```
Student_ID  | Exam               | Note
1           | Java               | 15
1           | Php                | 14
2           | Java               | 12
2           | Php                | 13
```

I want to get this in the same Tablix:

Student Name      | ID
Jack Luis         | 1
Adam Bob          | 2

---

```
Student_ID | Student Name | Exam   | Note
1          |Jack Luis     | Java   | 15
1          |Jack Luis     | Php    | 14
2          |Adam Bob      | Java   | 12
2          |Adam Bob      | Php    | 13
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reporting services: Join all field on a dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997770/reporting-services-join-all-field-on-a-dataset)

Comment: It is best practice to use a stored procedure a dataset and let SQL do this more efficiently than a lookup.   So just use one dataset which calls a stored procedure which puts the two tables together.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved using `LOOKUP` function. `LOOKUP` function joins multiple dataset using a common field in the involved datasets.

Create a tablix and  set the `DataSetName` property to your second dataset.

[image]

Drag and drop the fields to the columns you want to show. For the Student Name column use the following expression:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Student_id.Value,Fields!Student_id.Value,Fields!StudentName.Value,"DataSet21")
```

> In the above expression replace `DataSet21` by the actual name of your
>   first dataset.

It will preview something like this:

[image]

---

**UPDATE:** Grouping by a header row.

Add a tablix and set your second dataset in `DataSetName` property. Add `Exam` and `Note` fields to the corresponding columns.

[image]

Add a Parent Row Group.

[image]

In the Tablix group window select the Add group header checkbox and use the following expression:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Student_id.Value,
Fields!Student_id.Value,Fields!StudentName.Value,"DataSet21")
```

[image]

Delete the first column created by the previous grouping setting.

[image]

In the cell above `Exam` use the following expression:

```
="Student Name: " &
Lookup(Fields!Student_id.Value,Fields!Student_id.Value,Fields!StudentName.Value,"FirstDataSet")
```

Now select Exam and Note row and add a row above outside the group.

[image]

Type `Exam` and `Note` in the corresponding cell above `[Exam]` and `[Note]` fields.

Select the three cells in the first row, right click it and select `Merge Cells`.

It will preview something like this:

[image]

If you want to delete the first blank row, you can do it smoothly.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank You Mr alejandro zuleta

Comment: thank you Mr alejandro zuleta it is solved my problem :)

Comment: @YounesAKIL , if my answer solved your issue you can select it as correct by clicking on the left side in the correct symbol.[How does accepting an answer works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Mr **alejandro zuleta**

but i want the result like  this in the same Tablix (using groupin By Name)

```
Studant Name:Jack Luis

Exam   | Note
Java   | 15
Php    | 14


Studant Name:Adam Bob

Exam   | Note
Java   | 12
Php    | 13
```

Comment: This is not an answer you should delete it and edit your question to include this. Check my update.