# SSRS Retaining Certain Parameters from URL

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

I've built a report which requires three parameters (all of which are integers):

- `Month`
- `Year`
- `StaffId`

The parameter `StaffId` is assigned from a dataset by default and is hidden.

I'm linking from one report to another by building a URL like the following:

```
http://<Server>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%<Report>&rs:Command=Render&StaffId=5443&Month=3&Year=2015
```

Note - The server and report name are obviously specified in the URL!

The issue that I'm facing is that when running the above report, if I change the `Month` or `Year` parameter, `StaffId` is also updated from the dataset associated to it which is not the behavior that I would like.

What I would like is that if `StaffId` is specified in the URL, it should not change / be updated from the dataset. I would still want the user to be able to change `Month` and `Year`. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

I'm aware of parameter refreshing in the advanced parameter options but this does have the option for an expression.

**Edit**

I've tried using the 'Never Refresh' option but it still seems to refresh. In case it makes a difference, there is dependencies on the parameter.

Comment: "I'm aware of parameter refreshing in the advanced parameter options but this does have the option for an expression." I don't understand what you mean here - can you explain more about why you can't select the "never refresh" option for your StaffID parameter?

Comment: @TPhe I've tried using the 'Never Refresh' Option but it still seems to refresh when I update the month or year parameter.

Comment: Have you looked into making it an internal parameter instead of hidden? It may not work for your purposes because an internal parameter cannot be passed via url, but it seems like it can be passed from report to report by choosing parameters in a report drillthrough action. It also seems like they are "read only" and cannot be modified after being passed. I can't vouch that this will work, as I have never used them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179219/in-ssrs-how-does-an-internal-parameter-differ-from-a-hidden-parameter