# Can I programatically pass a parameter value to a PowerBI report?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I have an embedded PowerBI report that needs to execute a query with a parameter that changes depending on which client opens a report. I need to programatically pass the value of a parameter (that cannot be prepopulated inside a filter) so that I can then use this value to execute the SQL query.

Also this parameter should not be visible/modifiable to the reader of the report because they would be able to change the value and see data they were not supposed to see.

I tried passing a value programatically to a filter but the filter needs to contain the value in order to set the value being passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [Paginated Report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-paginated-report) using a Hidden Parameter, but not a Power BI Interactive Report.  See [In SSRS, how does an "Internal" parameter differ from a "hidden" parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179219/in-ssrs-how-does-an-internal-parameter-differ-from-a-hidden-parameter)

Comment: So there is no way to actually pass a parameter that would be used by a DirectQuery?

Comment: Not directly. You could use a Power App visual to write a value to your database.