# Can you set an Internal parameter using the Report Viewer control?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, webforms, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible to set an internal parameter value using the Report Viewer control?

```
rv.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { new ReportParameter("Username", User.Identity.Name) });
```

> {"The report parameter 'Username' is read-only and cannot be modified.
>   (rsReadOnlyReportParameter)"}

I've heard that you can only [set an internal parameter using the Report Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9844518/40822)...but it seems an internal parameter is just that...internal. To be clear, an internal parameter on the server side is one where both `Hide` and `Prompt` are not checked on the parameter definition. If `Hide` is checked (hidden parameter), the parameter can still be passed in via a query string or on a subscription.

Comment: In creating linked report the internal parameter gets exposed to user. So in this case internal parameter behaves same way as hidden parameter.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN - Creating Report Parameters and Setting Report Parameter Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337234.aspx):

> Hidden and Internal Parameters
>
> You can set options that control parameter visibility in the published
>   report. Setting the Hidden and Internal options provides different
>   levels of visibility. You can hide the parameter on the parameter
>   input area of the published report, yet set values for it on a report
>   URL or in a subscription definition. **If you set a parameter to
>   Internal, it is not exposed in any way except in the report
>   definition**. An internal parameter must have a default value, which can
>   be null if the Allow null value option has been selected.

---

### Update, after a bit of testing:

This is actually a confusing definition. The parameter is exposed in Report Viewer and the value can be easily overridden in the report properties and the properties of a linked report.

You are still unable to set the value of an internal parameter from the URL or from the drill-down action from another report. It is visible when you create the action but when you try to drill-down you get the error: `The report parameter 'name' is read-only and cannot be modified.` I wouldn't imagine you will be able to modify the value from code either, but I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was sending to SSRS by URL some parameters. I needed to  validate/edit the parameter if contains certain character. something like that:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Par1.Value Like "*]","[Table1].[Field1].&[" + Parameters!Par1.Value + "]]","[Table1].[Field1].&[" + Parameters!Par1.Value + "]")
```

In the Parameter Definitions. in "Select Parameter Visibility" I had marked the option: "Internal". I changed to "Hidden" and it allowed me to edit the parameter. why? no clues. but now is working